# ¿El espaciado vertical del código afecta la ejecución del mismo?

Tags: programación-funcional

Entiendo que la sangría o el espaciado horizontal no es importante en la mayoría de los lenguajes de programación, pero ¿el espaciado vertical o el interlineado afecta a la ejecución de un programa?

Comment: Gente, ¿Tres votos de cierre con el motivo "no está claro lo que se pregunta"?. ¿Que cosa no está clara? Al contrario, la pregunta es clarísima. Puede que sea una pregunta elemental, pero es totalmente válida, o a al menos eso me parce...

Comment: @PatricioMoracho estoy de acuerdo, la pregunta es clara. Esta pregunta no debería ser cerrada por sencilla que parezca.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay lenguajes en los que el espaciado horizontal es muy importante, como por ejemplo en Python. Sin embargo, hasta donde yo conozco, no hay ningún lenguaje (conocido) que de importancia al espaciado vertical.

Cuando un código se compila, se eliminan todos los espacios innecesarios y el código se "tokeniza", es decir, a cada palabra de tu código se le asigna una categoría. Esto consigue que tu código se traduzca en una lista de palabras que representan lo que tú has programado (el proceso está muy simplificado). Por lo tanto, yo diría que no, que el espaciado vertical se elimina en el momento de la compilación y no aporta nada al significado del programa.

**EDITO**

Como bien apunta Trauma en su comentario, hay algún lenguaje que sí da importancia al espaciado vertical, concretamente [Piet](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piet_(lenguaje_de_programaci%C3%B3n)). Sin embargo, se cataloga dentro de los lenguajes "esotéricos" o "exóticos", que son más bien lenguajes anecdóticos y no son demasiado usables o útiles en entornos reales o proyectos grandes.

Comment: Hay por lo menos 1: [Piet](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piet_(lenguaje_de_programaci%C3%B3n)).

Comment: No lo conocía, gracias por el apunte.